# Edit diff files

Tags: diff

I have a `.diff` file generated from comparing two directories. However, there are some folders and files that appear in the `.diff` that I want to remove from it, so I can get a cleaner `.diff`.

Is there any editor that lets me do this (something like Kompare, but it must allow to remove files from the diff)? How can I specify to exclude specific directories?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an editor, but it looks as if **filterdiff** from patchutils does what you're after:

> Filterdiff will select the portions of a patch file that apply to files matching (or, alternatively, not matching) a shell wildcard.

You can find out more about patchutils [here](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/) and it's packaged in Debian / Ubuntu as "patchutils".

Answer (score 1):

If you end up needing to do "real editing" of patch (diff) files, like adding and removing diffs, adding and removing lines from a diff, etc then you might consider running [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) which has a diff-editing mode that does the "right thing" when you go changing a diff file.  It has menu actions and key bindings for "kill current chunk" and similar actions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/)? There you can define filters to filer your comparisons. Otherwise it's a perfect GUI for diff.

Comment: I don't want to compare files. I just want to remove some files from an already made diff.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the creation of the `.diff` file, I think the best approach is to in the first place not include what you later want to ignore. Diff have a `--exclude-from=FILE` command line option where you can give it a list of all files you want to have excluded. Alternatively you can use `--exclude=PATTERN` to exclude based on file name matching.